# Sum-Product among corresponding columns - Pandas / Numpy

Tags: pandas, numpy

I want to add column and apply Sum-Product on corresponding columns (by name).

Data illustration:

```
 VAR1  VAR2  1834_Value  1673_Value  153_Value  0_Value  1834_Prob  0_Prob  1673_Prob  153_Prob
    4     1          10          20         30       40      0.100   0.400      0.200     0.300
    1     3          28          79         88       36      0.187   0.057      0.181     0.574
    3     3          30          72         59       95      0.227   0.050      0.171     0.552
    4     2          55          46         85       97        NaN     NaN        NaN       NaN
    1     2          28          41         62       64      0.251   0.092      0.084     0.573
    5     1          82          51         21       24        NaN     NaN        NaN       NaN
    2     2          27          90         71       83      0.114   0.003      0.131     0.751
    5     2          97          94         46       46      0.285   0.112      0.126     0.477
    2     5          27          66         73       44        NaN     NaN        NaN       NaN
    1     5          39          76         90       58        NaN     NaN        NaN       NaN
    5     2          63          71         47       92      0.279   0.163      0.212     0.346
```

For instance: the first row's value should be: `0.1*10 + 0.2*20 + 0.3*30 + 0.4*40` `=` `30`.

- Note: the columns are not arranged by order.

Expected result:

```
 VAR1  VAR2  1834_Value  1673_Value  153_Value  0_Value  1834_Prob  0_Prob  1673_Prob  153_Prob  SumProduct
    4     1          10          20         30       40      0.100   0.400      0.200     0.300      30.000
    1     3          28          79         88       36      0.187   0.057      0.181     0.574      72.175
    3     3          30          72         59       95      0.227   0.050      0.171     0.552      56.464
    4     2          55          46         85       97        NaN     NaN        NaN       NaN         NaN
    1     2          28          41         62       64      0.251   0.092      0.084     0.573      51.885
    5     1          82          51         21       24        NaN     NaN        NaN       NaN         NaN
    2     2          27          90         71       83      0.114   0.003      0.131     0.751      68.523
    5     2          97          94         46       46      0.285   0.112      0.126     0.477      66.570
    2     5          27          66         73       44        NaN     NaN        NaN       NaN         NaN
    1     5          39          76         90       58        NaN     NaN        NaN       NaN         NaN
    5     2          63          71         47       92      0.279   0.163      0.212     0.346      63.905
```

Comment: are columns labeled consistently? Like is 1834_value always multiplied by 1834_prob?

Comment: Yes,, they are.

Comment: how many VAR columns do you have?

Comment: There is integers list: `[0, 153, 1673, 1834]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's my approach:

```
s = df.iloc[:,2:]
df['sum_prod'] = (s.groupby(s.columns.str.extract('^(\d+)')[0].values, 
                            axis=1)
                   .prod(min_count=2).sum(1, skipna=False)
                 )

print(df['sum_prod'])
```

Output:

```
0     30.000
1     72.099
2     56.440
3        NaN
4     51.886
5        NaN
6     68.438
7     66.583
8        NaN
9        NaN
10    63.887
Name: sum_prod, dtype: float64
```

Comment: I've edited my question and added `NaN` values to the "Prob" columns. Also, updated the expected result.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way:

```
m=df.set_index(['VAR1','VAR2'])
m.groupby(m.columns.str.split('_').str[0],axis=1,sort=False).prod().sum(1) #.reset_index()
```

---

```
VAR1  VAR2
1     4       30.000
4     2       62.840
1     2       76.924
      1       55.196
      1       73.789
      2       63.813
2     5       43.824
```

Answer (score 1):

for simplicity, I would slice `_Value` into one dataframe and `_Prob` to another dataframe and just doing multiplication and sum

```
df_value = df.filter(like='_Value').sort_index(axis=1)
df_prob = df.filter(like='_Prob').sort_index(axis=1)
df['SumProduct'] = df_value.mul(df_prob.values).sum(1, skipna=False)

Out[604]:
    VAR1  VAR2  1834_Value  1673_Value  153_Value  0_Value  1834_Prob  0_Prob  \
0      4     1          10          20         30       40      0.100   0.400
1      1     3          28          79         88       36      0.187   0.057
2      3     3          30          72         59       95      0.227   0.050
3      4     2          55          46         85       97        NaN     NaN
4      1     2          28          41         62       64      0.251   0.092
5      5     1          82          51         21       24        NaN     NaN
6      2     2          27          90         71       83      0.114   0.003
7      5     2          97          94         46       46      0.285   0.112
8      2     5          27          66         73       44        NaN     NaN
9      1     5          39          76         90       58        NaN     NaN
10     5     2          63          71         47       92      0.279   0.163

    1673_Prob  153_Prob  SumProduct
0       0.200     0.300      30.000
1       0.181     0.574      72.099
2       0.171     0.552      56.440
3         NaN       NaN         NaN
4       0.084     0.573      51.886
5         NaN       NaN         NaN
6       0.131     0.751      68.438
7       0.126     0.477      66.583
8         NaN       NaN         NaN
9         NaN       NaN         NaN
10      0.212     0.346      63.887
```

Answer (score 1):

What you essentially require is a element-wise multiplication of columns followed by sum along axis 1

```
columns = ['1834',  '1673',  '153',  '0']

values = df[f"{i}_Value" for i in columns].values
probs = df[f"{i}_Prob" for i in columns].values

df['sum_product'] = np.multiply(values, probs).sum(axis = 1)
```